# Alpine linux as router - Hurricane electric/ tunnel broker 6in4 not routing packets to LAN

Tags: ipv6, tunnel, alpine-linux

I'm trying to IPv6 working. I'm using alpine Linux as my router. So far I've go the tunnel up on my router. My router can ping6 ipv6.google.com and receives a reply.

I've set up router advertisements with radvd. Hosts on the network are getting IPv6 addresses from the RAs. however they cannot access ipv6 only websites like ipv6.google.com. they cannot ping these sites either. I can see they're able to lookup the ipv6 address.

From my packet captures, when hosts are pinging, they're receiving a reply but the router doesn't appear to be forwarding the ipv6 back to the lan interface (br0).

Packet capture on he-ipv6 interface

```
10:14:44.483729 IP6 fe80::d8da:8e32 > fe80::ca82:d707: ICMP6, destination unreachable, beyond scope mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net, source address fe80::ca82:d707, length 208
10:14:45.464047 IP6 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee > mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net: ICMP6, echo request, id 10119, seq 4, length 64
10:14:45.490016 IP6 mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net > 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee: ICMP6, echo reply, id 10119, seq 4, length 64
10:14:45.490121 IP6 fe80::ca82:d707 > mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net: ICMP6, redirect, 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee to 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee, length 160
10:14:45.490155 IP6 mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net > 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee: ICMP6, echo reply, id 10119, seq 4, length 64
10:14:45.502716 IP6 fe80::d8da:8e32 > fe80::ca82:d707: ICMP6, destination unreachable, beyond scope mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net, source address fe80::ca82:d707, length 208
10:14:46.487898 IP6 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee > mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net: ICMP6, echo request, id 10119, seq 5, length 64
10:14:46.514088 IP6 mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net > 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee: ICMP6, echo reply, id 10119, seq 5, length 64
10:14:46.514191 IP6 fe80::ca82:d707 > mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net: ICMP6, redirect, 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee to 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee, length 160
10:14:46.514224 IP6 mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net > 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee: ICMP6, echo reply, id 10119, seq 5, length 64
10:14:46.527771 IP6 fe80::d8da:8e32 > fe80::ca82:d707: ICMP6, destination unreachable, beyond scope mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net, source address fe80::ca82:d707, length 208
```

capture on lan br0

```
10:12:04.244145 IP6 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee > mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net: ICMP6, echo request, id 9210, seq 2, length 64
10:12:05.268171 IP6 2001:470:1f2c:103:9f3f:91cc:8361:eeee > mel05s01-in-x0e.1e100.net: ICMP6, echo request, id 9210, seq 3, length 64
10:12:06.788906 IP6 2001:470:1f2c:103:68ea:b849:5a38:674f.49780 > dns.google.443: Flags [SEW], seq 885084687, win 65535, options [mss 1420,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3846476528 ecr 0,sackOK,tfo  cookiereq], length 0
```

ipv6 forwarding is enabled in the kernal and ip6tables is installed and starts on boot.

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
#Ipv6 config
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding= 1
net.ipv6.conf.he-ipv6.accept_ra=2
```

ip6tables config

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate ESTABLISHED
icmp-routing  58   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  *redacted*::/64  ::/0                
ACCEPT     6    --  ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     17   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     17   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:51820
ACCEPT     58   --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                


Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate ESTABLISHED
icmp-routing  58   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED
ACCEPT     6    --  ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     17   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     17   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:51820
icmp-routing  58   --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                


Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate ESTABLISHED
icmp-routing  58   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     58   --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                
ACCEPT     0    --  ::/0                 ::/0                


Chain icmp-routing (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     58   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 1
ACCEPT     58   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 2
ACCEPT     58   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 3
ACCEPT     58   --  ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 4
```

iptables  output

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         


Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate ESTABLISHED
icmp-routing  1    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED
ACCEPT     6    --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.145        tcp dpt:53 ctstate DNAT
ACCEPT     17   --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.145        udp dpt:53 ctstate DNAT
ACCEPT     17   --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:51820
icmp-routing  1    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         


Chain icmp-routing (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     1    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
ACCEPT     1    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
ACCEPT     1    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
```

I've added the following to /etc/hosts as recommended by https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Configure_Networking

```
::1 localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback

fe00::0 ipv6-localnet

ff00::0 ipv6-mcastprefix

ff02::1 ipv6-allnodes

ff02::2 ipv6-allrouters

ff02::3 ipv6-allhosts
```

Contents of my /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp


auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
bridge-ports eth1 eth2



auto he-ipv6

iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel

address 2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::2

netmask 64

endpoint 216.218.142.50

local 

ttl 255

gateway 2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::1
```

I added the static ip to br0 with this

```
/sbin/ip addr add 2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::2/64 dev br0
```

I followed this tutorial to set up radvd https://chronos-tachyon.net/reference/debian-ipv6-and-hurricane-electric/ the contents of my /etc/radvd.conf is

```
interface br0 {

  AdvSendAdvert on;
  AdvLinkMTU 1480;
  MinRtrAdvInterval 60;
  MaxRtrAdvInterval 180;
  prefix  2001:aaaa:bbbb:ccc::1/64 {
    AdvOnLink on;
    AdvRouterAddr on;
    AdvPreferredLifetime 600;
    AdvValidLifetime 3600;
  };
  route ::/0 {};
RDNSS 2001:470:20::2 {};
};
```

I bring up the tunnel with this command

```
modprobe ipv6

ip tunnel add he-ipv6 mode sit remote 216.218.142.50 local 202.aaa.bbb.ccc.d ttl 255

ip link set he-ipv6 up

ip addr add 2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::2/64 dev he-ipv6

ip route add ::/0 dev he-ipv6

ip -f inet6 addr
```

I tried adding this command as well

```
ip tunnel 6rd dev he-ipv6 6rd-prefix 2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:/64 6rd-relay_prefix 216.218.142.50/32
```

I also tried the tunnel with a local ip

```
ip tunnel add he-ipv6 mode sit remote 216.218.142.50 local 192.168.1.1 ttl 255
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. any help would be appreciated.